# Adobe air android install but open is disable

Tags: android, air, adobe

I am installing an app that I have build for android. 
It install fine but the but the "Open" button in the end is disabled and it doesn't create a shortcut 
 at all How can I debug or try to understand what is going wrong there

Air version 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the devices LogCat in order to debug this. You can access the LogCat via the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) or [there are several apps you can install on the device](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=logcat&c=apps&hl=en)